# how to sort file names having string plus date plus number

Tags: php, string, sorting, date, numbers

I wrote a script to get all the files from a given directory and upload those files to my site. However, I am facing a problem - when I print my filenames of the directory those are coming as follows.

```
Products010420141400170007.xml

Products010420141402380008.xml

Products010420141406240009.xml

Products100320141739560000.xml

Products180320142116150001.xml

Products180320142121210002.xml

Products210320141150070003.xml

Products240320141643400004.xml

Products310320141848450005.xml
```

But I need them to sort on the basis of date and the last numbers. Filename format is

```
"Productsddmmyyhis0001.xml"

Products100320141739560000.xml
Products180320142116150001.xml
Products180320142121210002.xml
Products210320141150070003.xml
Products240320141643400004.xml
Products310320141848450005.xml
Products010420141400170007.xml
Products010420141402380008.xml
Products010420141406240009.xml
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your answer guys.

I **solved** it like this. Can you tell me is it fine for future, currently it is working fine.

```
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");      

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $length =   strlen($file);
            $key    =   substr($file,22,($length-22));

            $final_array[$key]  = $file;    

        }
        ksort($final_array);
```

Comment: You want it formatted that way in what situation when you grab it ? or in the folder structure ?

Comment: Are the file names in an an array?

Comment: @NetaMeta when I grab these files. I have update my question also please check it

Comment: @Grim... yes these are in array. I have update my question also please check it

Comment: You have to use `usort` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: well you have several options, 1, you can break the names into multid array and then multi sort, second option is when you save the dates, save them in unix number form and they should be sorted by themselves

Comment: @NetaMeta I do not save the files.I just need to write the code for grabbing files and upload on my server

Comment: is the name of the files is a constant ? will it stay that way always ?

Comment: @NetaMeta format is "Productsddmmyyhis0001.xml" then "Productsddmmyyhis0002.xml" and so on "Productsddmmyyhis100000000.xml"

Comment: well you're going to have to parse the file name. give me a sec..

Answer (score 3):

While parsing can be done with regex, in your case it's better with [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr)

```
$files = [
'Products010420141400170007.xml',
'Products010420141402380008.xml',
'Products010420141406240009.xml',
'Products100320141739560000.xml',
'Products180320142116150001.xml',
'Products180320142121210002.xml',
'Products210320141150070003.xml',
'Products240320141643400004.xml',
'Products310320141848450005.xml'
];

$f = function($z, $offset)
{
   return strtotime(
      sprintf(
         '%s.%s.%s %s:%s:%s',
         substr($z, $offset,    2),
         substr($z, $offset+2,  2),
         substr($z, $offset+6,  4),
         substr($z, $offset+10, 2),
         substr($z, $offset+12, 2),
         substr($z, $offset+14, 2)
      )
   );
};

usort($files, function($x, $y) use ($f)
{
   $dx = $f($x, 8);
   $dy = $f($y, 8);
   if($dx==$dy)
   {
      return substr($x, 22, 4)-substr($y, 22, 4);
   }
   return $dx-$dy;
});
```

-since `substr()` will work much faster. Note, that code above is bound to file name structure and will fail if there will be invalid entries.

It will parse file name with extracting date & time parts with offset and then, if corresponding timestamps are equal, compare numeric (4 digits) postfixes.

Comment: You've got my vote for the fast answer. And yes, that breaks once the count exceeds 99.

Comment: Why would it break at 99 ?

Comment: thanks @alma.Can you tell me is my answer also fine.I have updated my question with answer

Comment: user3110655 his solution is the fastest and best one out of the ones you got. just use it.

Comment: Well, in your case you can't rely that dates as string would always be compared properly (for example `31122013hhmmssxxxxxx > 01012014hhmmssxxxxxx` as strings, but it's incorrect in terms of dates)

Comment: @AlmaDo yes you are right in terms of date but I need files to be sorted and it is also sure that last numbers of file name will always be increasing. In that case my code is fine I think. ??

Comment: Not sure what are you telling about. It's exclusive - either comparison as dates is ok or comparison as strings is ok. My code will produce comparison as dates. If you want comparison as dates, then your code isn't valid

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is : "Products{ddmmyyyyhhmmss}XXXX.xml"

You should try :

```
$all = [...]; // array of string with every files names;

$files = array();

foreach($all as $name) {
    $year= substr($name,12,4);
    $month = substr($name,10,2);
    $day = substr($name,8,2);
    $hour = substr($name,16,2);
    $min = substr($name,18,2);
    $sec = substr($name,20,2);
    $key = mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$month,$day,$year);
    // you got your timestamp

    $files[$key] = $name;
}

foreach($files as $name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

It should display your files from the oldest to the most recent.
But you've got a kind of sorted array. If you want classical keys :

```
// instead of the last foreach :
$all = array();
foreach($files as $name) {
    $all[] = $name;
}

// for reversed array : (recent first)
array_reverse($all);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following function to sort files name:

Based on the requirement filename is in this format: Productsddmmyyhis100000000.xml

So the following function will sort filenames based on year, month, date and file number respectively.

```
// Main funcion to sort filenames
function sort_files($files)
{
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $key = substr($file, 12, 4) . substr($file, 10, 2) . substr($file, 8, 2) . substr($file, 16);
        $temp_array[$key] = $file;
    }
    ksort($temp_array);

    return $temp_array;
}
$files = array(
    "Products010420141400170007.xml",
    "Products010420141402380008.xml",
    "Products010420141406240009.xml",
    "Products100320141739560000.xml",
    "Products180320142116150001.xml",
    "Products180320142121210002.xml",
    "Products210320141150070003.xml",
    "Products240320141643400004.xml",
    "Products310320141848450005.xml"
);
$sorted_files = sort_files($files);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($sorted_files, TRUE) . "</pre>";
```